# Perl split regex with delimiter-prefix

Tags: regex, perl, split

I want to split if in front of the delimiter if there is NOT a special character.

```
my $str = "a,b,c,d,e";
my @lst = split (/,/, $str);

# gives me: ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

# now I want to split after any , with not a character c in front of the ,.
# ("a", "b", "c,d", "e")
```

I tried

```
split (/(?!c),/, $str)
```

but it was not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [negative look behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that which checks backwards.

```
split (/(?<!c),/, $str)
```